# minified scripts not working one server

Tags: javascript, encoding, minify

I'm sorry if this is obvious or already answered, but I'm searching for a solution for hours now.

I made a very simple website and it's working perfectly on my own hosting.
But when I move it to the new hosting (same company, same pack, different server probalby) none of the minified files are working.

Not the minified CSS files, nor the JS files are working. Unminified they work perfectly.

When I put the exact same files on my own hosting and I link to the files from my html on the second server, everything is fine. But as soon as I move them to the same server where the website is on, they don't work anymore.

It's driving me crazy.
It does that with every minified file, even the minified jQuery versions I download from the official website. So I don't expect it to be a problems with the files. 
The error I get in the debugger are a bunch of red dots and strange character, so I think the problem has to be something with the encoding, but I can't figure out what the problem is.

Any suggestions?
Thanks a lot.

[image]
[image]

Comment: add description of what kind of errors you are getting, maybe a screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Well, I just did the same thing I did 3 times already and I uploaded all the files again on the new server and the problem seems to be resolved.

It still puzzles me what went wrong, and I cant really give the answer apart from that there would have been a problem when uploading the files, 3 times in a row and only with minified files, but all went good the fourth time.